# Rails GET request "The network connection was lost."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I have a Rails app that has an API that proxies requests to another server and caches them. One of the endpoints that it proxies is a GET request that returns a gif. On the server side, the GET request works fine (using HTTParty). I logged out the data that it gets and it's all there. Then, I render that data on the rails side to the client. Everything works fine when running the rails app locally, but in production the requests from the rails app never finishes. I just get "The network connection was lost." when cURLing the endpoint. As I said, I logged out the data from the GET request in production and it's all there, it just never gets to the client.

Let me know if there's some more information that I can provide. Thanks for any help.

Comment: May I suggest a way to clarify this question? I see at least five nouns up there, some of which seem to refer to the same thing(s), e.g. 'Rails app', 'API', 'another server', 'endpoints', 'server side', 'rails side'. Maybe a diagram with some labels would clarify which stage of the roundtrip is causing trouble and get someone closer to a useful answer for you.

Comment: Also, you must have a small section of code in which you make the request which is causing you trouble. Perhaps posting that would reveal an issue.

Comment: So, in other words, your app works. What are the differences between your 'local' and production environment such that in the production environment the cached data isn't reaching the client?

Comment: can you tcp dump the request from the production webserver ? to see if the data is coming back, but as other have said, what is different between production and dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel like an idiot. For some reason I never thought to check the nginx error log. When I did, I found the following:

```
2014/09/16 11:42:36 [crit] 8957#0: *12727 open() "/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/4/13/0000000134" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream...
```

All I had to do was make sure that my nginx user had permission to the /var/cache/nginx directory. Now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

So outside of your application environment if you run `curl` from the command line on the external service from your production server do you get the same result as your development machine? If those are different then there is something different about the way the external service is serving to your different machines.

If they are the same then try running your app on your development box in the production environment (or configure your development environment to match production's) and see if you can get it to fail locally.  Try and make your development machine match your production environment as much as possible (safely of course).

Answer (score 0):

Does your production environment have any request timeout limits?  For example Heroku limits requests to 30 seconds.